# How can I change the texture of a prefab clone when it's clicked?

Tags: unity, c#, sprites, input, picking

I have a prefab (called ArableLand), and when I click on the ground in the play mode, the ArableLand prefab instantiates a clone of itself.

For example, if I click 3 times on 3 different places, then 3 clones of the ArableLand prefab will be instantiated.

I have 2 Boolean variables:

- PlantCarrot
- PlantBanana

To go with this, I also have 2 sprites:

- PlantedCarrotSprite
- PlantedBananaSprite

When I click on an ArableLand instance, and I have for example PlantCarrot set to true, I want this instance's texture to turn into PlantedCarrotSprite.

If I have more than 1 clone of this prefab, then I want to change the **clicked** clone's texture, not any other (at least until I click the other one as well).

How can I do this?

Here is the script I currently use on the ArableLand prefab:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FarmingSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    //the plant panel is made out of buttons which contain the booleans I mentioned before
    public GameObject PlantPanel;
    //this is a script in the PlantPanel
    public Plant plantScr;

    //Sprites of planted food
    public Sprite PlantedCarrotSprite;
    public Sprite PlantedBananaSprite;

    //Check if plant is planted
    public bool IsCarrotPlanted;
    public bool IsBananaPlanted;

    public void Start()
    {
        PlantPanel = GameObject.Find("Canvas/PlantPanelObj/PlantPanel");

        plantScr = GameObject.Find("Canvas/PlantPanelObj/PlantPanel").GetComponent<Plant>();;
    }

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        PlantPanel.SetActive(true);

        if (plantScr.PlantButtonNumber == 1 && plantScr.Carrot != null)
        {
            PlantCarrotFarm();
        }
        
        if (plantScr.PlantButtonNumber == 2 && plantScr.Banana != null)
        {
            PlantBananaFarm();
        }
    }

    public void PlantCarrotFarm()
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = PlantedCarrotSprite;
        IsCarrotPlanted = true;
        Destroy(plantScr.Carrot.gameObject);
    }

    public void PlantBananaFarm()
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = PlantedBananaSprite;
        IsBananaPlanted = true;
        Destroy(plantScr.Banana.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Here's the screenshot of how the ArableLand prefab looks:
[image]

Comment: This script looks like it's already set up to change the texture of the single instance whose collider component was clicked. Are you observing some other behaviour when you use this?

Comment: @DMGregory well, it's actually changing the sprite of the first intantiated prefab clone, even if I click on any other.

Comment: Can you show us how this prefab and its collider are set up in your inspector and scene view? My first guess is the collider is too big so it's catching clicks on other objects.

Comment: Done, I edited the question